# Can I set the default image type for home/paste special/picture?

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste

If I'm about to paste, say, a graph copied from Excel (just the default "copy" command), I can select Paste/Special in Word to get a dropdown menu to select PNG, JPG, GIF, and a few others.

If I just click the "Paste" icon in the ribbon, a mini-palette appears with several options, one of which is "picture".  Notice that it doesn't specify what image format the picture will be pasted as.

Is there any way to set the format (PNG, JPG, etc.) that this ribbon sub-button selects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Word 2010, when you use that option the format saved is **PNG**. Not sure if this varies with other Word versions.

While I am not aware of a way to change this, if you want to frequently Paste as a particular type, and want to save a few clicks, you could setup a macro/Sub that performs the Paste, and then add this to your Ribbon or Quick Access Toolbar. For example, to Save as **GIF**, you could use:

> Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=13, Placement:=wdInLine,
>   DisplayAsIcon:=False

If you wanted **JPG**, code would be:

> Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=15, Placement:=wdInLine,
>   DisplayAsIcon:=False

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is no! I'm sorry to say so and perhaps someone else knows something but I can't find anything on the Internet or in the Word Preferences and have never heard of an option like this existing.